# OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [] in SignedJwtAssertionCredentials attempt

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client, pyopenssl

I'm trying to login with SignedJwtAssertionCredentials to get [gspread](https://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to work. I've followed the directions [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) with the notes for python3. Here's my class:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

    class GoogleSpreadsheet():
        def fetch(self):
            gc = gspread.authorize(self.credentials)
            wks = gc.open("TEST of Sheet (Responses)").sheet1
            print(wks)

        def __init__(self, client_email,pk):
                scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
                self.credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, bytes(pk, 'utf-8'), scope)
```

with `client_email` and `pk` being passed from environment variables:

```
gs = GoogleSpreadsheet(app.config.get('GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_CLIENT_EMAIL'), app.config.get('GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_PK'))
```

The environment variable is copied from the google auth json file:

```
export GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_PK="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n...keystuff...\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

It errors out every attempt with `OpenSSL.crypto.Error: []`

The suggestion here [Loading private key fails with OpenSSL.crypto.Error: []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459437/loading-private-key-fails-with-openssl-crypto-error) didn't help since my key isn't encrypted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from this thread: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/193
and some fiddling, it looks like you need to turn the `\n`'s in the private key into real newlines if you're not loading the config file though `JSON.load` (which the gsheets tutorial does.)

Comment: I found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25435674/888970) to be helpful in illustrating exactly what is meant by use `json.load`.

Comment: This answer was key.

Comment: for whoever is trying to read a private key from a .env file this solved my issue:

`PRIVATE_KEY = os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY', "").replace('\\n', "\n")`